# C# API Get Request with Basic Authentication - Server is Returning (403) Forbidden

Tags: c#

I'm attempting to make a connection to an API endpoint. I'm getting (403) Forbidden. I was hoping someone could help me figure out what I'm doing wrong with this. Here's my code:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;                  

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {        
        string token = "Username:Password";
        byte[] pwd = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(token);
        String encodedPassword = Convert.ToBase64String(pwd, 0, pwd.Length, Base64FormattingOptions.None);

        String PostData = ("Authorization: Basic " + encodedPassword);

        var myUri = new Uri("http://EndPoint URL");
        var myWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(myUri);
        var myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)myWebRequest;
        
        myHttpWebRequest.PreAuthenticate = true;
        myHttpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedPassword);
        myHttpWebRequest.Accept = "application/json";

        var myWebResponse = myWebRequest.GetResponse();
        var responseStream = myWebResponse.GetResponseStream();
        var myStreamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.Default);
        var json = myStreamReader.ReadToEnd();

        responseStream.Close();
        myWebResponse.Close();      
    }
}
```

Comment: The user/password combination may not have access to the resource you are requesting.  Without knowing how that resource works, its not possible for us to say what kind of permissions you must have.

Comment: When I submit the request to the endpoint using reqbin.com, with GET and Basic Auth selected,  it works.

Comment: Not sure if it makes any difference but I'm using dotnetfiddle.net to test the code.  I've also tried the code generated by reqbin.com and it too gives me forbidden.

Comment: Do u have any documentation available to you about the endpoint you are trying to request?

Comment: https://ims.fileboundrs.com/api/documentation

Comment: This is the one in particular I've been trying: 
 https://ims.fileboundrs.com/api/documentation#projects-endpoint

Comment: do you get any response body with 403 status code?

Comment: I get this:Run-time exception (line 24): The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

Comment: I apologize for the wild goose chase.  I found out that the endpoint does not allow basic authentication, the request must be authenticated with a guid.